Why the coupling constant in context of different approaches has different energy dependence?
I know that in the language of renormalization group, the coupling constant in the Hamiltonian is dependent of energy, for example in condensed matter physics, of band width. So, we can do a 'poor man's scaling' to obtain a low energy effective Hamiltonian, in particular the Kondo Hamiltonian.
An alternative approach is the equation of motion, we can solve a set of hierarchical equations to obtain one-particle Green function, which to some extent incorporate the information of low energy physics. But in this process, we seem use the original coupling constant all the way, it seems that the coupling constant is independent of energy.
(In perturbation theory, actually, I know that the coupling, or to say the interaction, can be corrected, but which also use the original coupling constant.)
I want to know what's the subtle difference between above two approaches (or three approaches).
